# Select range based on header name

Tags: excel, vba

i want to select a column based on its' name, i found the range.find works, however i have cells with similar name beginnings, like "name" and "name id", when i do :

```
Set rng = Range(Range("A1:BR1").Find("name id"), Range("A1:BR1").Find("name id").End(xlDown))
```

it returns the range "name" as it is right before the "name id" column, is there a way to make the range.find, match the full name perfectly.

Thank you

Comment: `Range.Find` has a `LookAt` parameter which you should *definitely* specify.

Comment: @BigBen can you please tell me how to specify a optional parametre, i did this : 
Set rng = Range(Range("A1:BR1").Find("name id", XlLookAt(xlWhole)), Range("A1:BR1").Find("name id", XlLookAt(xlWhole)).End(xlDown))

after searching for the values of LookAt, if you can please tell me how to define that.

My apologies i'm still new to VBA.

Comment: Did you look at the linked duplicate? Or the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)?

Comment: @BigBen yes i looked at the doc first, but didnt find the full thing, i just checked the duplicate link, and found how
Set rng = Range(Range("A1:BR1").Find(what:="name id", LookAt:=xlWhole), Range("A1:BR1").Find(what:="name id", LookAt:=xlWhole).End(xlDown))

Thanks for your reply, and sorry for the duplicates!